# JSON Schema: XOR on required fields

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, required-field

JSON Schemas have [a `required` property](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required), which lists the required fields in a JSON object. For example, the following (simplified) schema validates a call that sends a text message to a user:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "userId":    { "type": "string" },
    "text":      { "type": "string" },
  },
  "required": ["userId", "text"]
}
```

Suppose that I want to enable sending the message to multiple users, i.e. have either a `userId` field, or an array of `userIds` (but not both or neither). Is there a way to express such a condition in a JSON Schema?

Naturally, there are ways to overcome the problem in this case - for example, a `userId` array with a single element - but the general case is interesting and useful.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably sorted this out by now, but this will do the trick using `oneOf` on the `type` of the field.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "userId": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "text": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["userId", "text"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant at all, but I think you can hack it out from `allOf` and `oneOf`. Something like:

```
 {
   "allOf" : [
      {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          // base properties come here
        }
      },
      "oneOf" : [
        {
        "properties" : {
             "userIds" : {"type" : "array"}
          },
          "required" : ["userIds"]
        },
        {
          "properties" : {
             "userId" : {"type" : "number"}
          },
          "required" : ["userId"]
        }
      ]
   ]
}
```